# Problems with dismantling GR8 lamp socket

Tags: lamp

Switching my lamps from fluorescent bulbs to LEDs (GR8 socket).

While dismantling the lamp, I accidentally pulled out the cord, as seen in the topmost picture, and I can't get it back. The other cord seems tight as well, and feels like a I have to brute force to pull it off, no?

I tried pushing the little plastic handle (advice I found online) on the other side, but apparently broke it. I'm not even sure if this is what should be done to get cords loose?

Can I still use this old GR8 socket to install the lamp or is it toast? I bought wire and new switch terminal, but GR8 sockets are rare and I would need to order them abroad.

[image]

Comment: you should be able to just shove the wire back in there.

Comment: It is possible the backstab will grab if trying to put back in,  I thought the op was removing the wires. I would get a t-pin or hat pin and push the stab down this usually releases the wire

Comment: take the cover off ... the latch is seen in the second picture above your thumb

Comment: Those little round holes there, any chance they have a slot in them for a screwdriver?